# Some UI elements are unable to tap/click in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

I build an table that can choose multiple cells.
But when run it in iPhone 8 Plus simulator, the cells are often unable to click, then I should return to previous page and go back to the table, make it work(usually should return and go back several times).
But sometime it does work normally.

iPhone X simulator also has this problem, but seems not so frequently.

[Pic of the table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bix4B.png)

What's the cause and solution? Thanks

Comment: have you use any custom font? which are not include in project?

Comment: Have you tried visual debugger? Could be a unexpected transparent view over your table.

Answer (score -1):

ios Version? try ios 10

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
self.tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
}else {
  self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I've changed the description because just now I found iPhone X simulator has this bug too.My project is running on iOS 11. I'll try ur solution